# Shrinkage of free disk space (Windows XP)

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp

Before you tell me I should change the system, I tell you that my laptop has CPU Pentium Dual Core 2GHz and 2GB RAM, so I don't think newer version of Windows than XP will work on that (maybe 7, if I get one and use minimal settings), and installing Xubuntu or any other Linux distribution means all the games I have and like are going bye bye, probably forever. Not to mention ability of using scanners and printers...

Where free disk space in Windows XP dissapears? I use CCleaner on weekly basis and I recently compressed C:/WINDOWS/Installer (biggest disk space eater, according to WinDirStat) and I got finally 14% of free disk space - for a couple of days. Now again I have only 11% of free disk space and I have no idea why...
Of course I could gain most of disk space by deleting C:/WINDOWS (biggest catalog on C disk), but I can't do that, for obvious reasons. My files take less than 10% of total used disk space.

Total disk C space - 39,06 GB, used - 34,53GB, free - 4,5GB. My Documents and Settings catalog takes 5,40 GB. CCleaner frees 500MB of disk space, at best. C:/WINDOWS - 12,3 GB.

the D partition has 193,8GB total, used 172,5 and free about 20GB. It doesn't contains system files, so it's easier to delete files there. All games are installed on D partition. Music I download (from jamendo and ektoplazm.com) and rip from bought CDs also goes there. 
Well, I can always save my files on D partiton (I already moved my photos there), but it hardly changes anything.

Buy another disk? We're talking about laptop here.

"vssadmin 1.0 - administracyjne narzędzie wiersza polecenia Usługi kopiowania woluminów w tle
(C) Copyright 2001 Microsoft Corp.

W systemie brak kopii w tle." - no backgound copies. I hardly see this information useful at this moment.

Comment: You have given us percentages but have not actually given us actual numbers in units that mean anything, nor have you, actually told us what folders are using your space.  Given that HDDs are so cheap, wouldn't it be easier to stop fighting your system, and just get a bigger HDD?  Edit your question;  Be sure you are running, WinDirStat, as an Administrator.  Since your using Windows XP you don't have ANY of the tools to reduce the size of your windows installation available to you.

Comment: At minimum Windows XP requires 15GB.  So provide us specifics.  The minimum usage doesn't include any of the updates.  Since Windows XP doesn't have the tool to superseed patches, and reduce the installation size by doing so, your stuck installing each individual patch which takes up space.

Comment: If you ran WinDirStat as an Administrator it would your actual disk usage would match the amount of space you have used and that is free.  You have left something else, EDIT YOUR QUESTION, to include ALL relevant information.  Let's cleanup the comment section shall we?  I am particularlly interested in your File History settings ( i.e. VSS ), aka, use `vssadmin list shadowstorage`

Comment: How big is the hard drive you are using? That would be a great start as Ramhound is eluding to.

Comment: It is only a 40 gb drive?! Definitely buy a new hard drive. Don't beat your head over nothing

Comment: Have you turned off system restore and removed associated files and removed service pack backup files and other items via windows disk cleanup?  You can also move the installer folder the D drive if you are a power user by moving it and creating a junction.  Research this before doing it though to understand the caveats.

Comment: Although on Ebay you can get a bigger drive for $10+/-.  $35 +/- for an Intel 320 SSD.  This would be simpler, easier, more effective, and could boost performance dramatically if you go the SSD route.  Why fight it?

Comment: XP wouldn't support a SSD though, right? Of course that system should handle 7 or 10 fine. Also its vaguely possible its pre SATA

Comment: You should be able to show hidden and protected files and delete (or move to other partition) the $<name> folders in the `C:\Windows` folder right there at the root (yes all of them, it's fine; test or move to the "D" drive instead if you wish... Done it thousands of times back in the XP day and still got Windows Updates fine back then).... You might also run `net stop /Y "Automatic Updates"` and
`net stop /Y "Background Intelligent Transfer Service"` and then `DEL /F /S /Q C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\*.*`

Comment: did you read Windows 10's requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Normally win xp only needs less than 15GB as Microsoft says. practically i installed and used win xp with 6GB drive without any problems. I think you should first do a full scan with a good anti virus program. try disk analyzer program to find what files are taking space in how much capacity. The one i use is a tool that comes with tune-up utilities. it is not free software though. there should be plenty of free alternatives available.Google for it.
then post results here.
or if none of these works, then you can try re installing windows xp as a final resort

Answer (score 0):

There are, generally speaking, three reasons for why you may see your free space shrinking:

1. Temporary files - these are files that are created by almost every piece of software running on your computer and are used to hold data for a short amount of time. Some programs clean up their temporary files (it may depend on the way they are configured) but most don't and these files can end up taking up a lot of space. The most effective solution to this problem would be to install cleanup software like CCleaner, you generally only need to configure it once and run it regularly to keep the temporary files from accumulating. You can also set it up to automatically run the clear on a schedule.
2. System restore which is a functionality of the operating system that allows you to restore critical system files to an earlier version in an event that some of them become corrupted. On Windows XP especially System Restore is known to store a lot of restore points, way more than are necessary (from personal experience I can say that having restore points farther than a week ago is pretty useless since restoring from that point means a lot of changes that you've done get undone and at that point you might as well save yourself the hassle and simply reinstall the OS). Long story short you can delete some of the oldest restore points to get some space back (remember to keep a few of the most recent ones though - I once used a restore point to fix a Windows XP OS that refused to boot up because of corrupted registry files).
3. In a rare situation that your system needs more memory than your RAM and pagefile can provide the OS may make the pagefile larger. The pagefile is a file that your OS treats as space to store data that was originally stored in RAM but wasn't used for a while and needed to be freed because of new data that needed to be moved into RAM. The solution here is to go into advanced system settings and remove the pagefile, restart the OS and recreate the pagefile with a smaller size (It is recommended for the pagefile to be at least as large as the amount of RAM in your computer).

I won't preach to you about how you should get a new computer since you probably heard it often enough. I would advise you to buy an external hard drive for your data. Not only will it allow you to free some space on your internal hard drive but you can also use it as a backup if your hard drive fails.